# A static page view call every custom page templates

Tags: pages

I use wordpress 3.9.1 and I get this strange issue:

I created a static page with slug `customer-order` and I created a template `page-customer-order.php` and Permalink: `http://localhost/thanassis/src/customer-order/`

I also created a static page with slug `zipfile` and I created a template `page-zipfile.php` and Permalink: `http://localhost/thanassis/src/zipfile`.

I also use child theme and these templates are in the child-theme folder.

The problem is that when I view `customer-order` page the wordpress not run only the correct template but also run the `zipfile` page template.
Is this correct Wordpress's sequence?

Comment: this is not normal behavior. is your theme a child of one of the core-bundled themes? I would try with a core-bundled theme and no plugins to figure out the cause of this.

Comment: Yes I use twentytwelve. I am not sure if this happened before. I created one more page `downloadfile` and template `page-downloadfile.php` to use instead `zipfile` and in this case the wp continue to run only two templates.

Comment: Can you just use native PHP `include()` to include the file where you want it?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I didn't tell that I used `include()`. Just I use the way of wordpress documentation to add a page template file.